# how to use include_vars in ansible

Tags: include, ansible, ansible-vault

I have created my own custom library, I added my custom library in the common folder of my repository. In that I need to pass variables dynamically. It's a confidential password, so I am using "vault" in ansible.

In that my requirement is how to pass `include_vars` in the `tasks\main.yml` before hosts.

e.g: mytasks.yml

```
- include_vars: sample_vault.yml
- include: sample_tasks.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    name: "free task"
    command: ls -a
```

my directory structure like this:

```
myfolder
  - common 
      -library   
         -my file.py
      - sample_tasks.yml

  - mytasks
      -mytasks.yml(my main master playbook file)
      -sample_vault.yml  (note:i create this using vault for confidential purpose)
      - roles
        -myrole
```

Here I need to run sample_tasks file using a variables passed in `sample_vault.yml` file before I execute the hosts tasks using ansible. If I use extra variable means password is visible so I don't need that.

When I use `include_vars` in my `tasks/main.yml` file, it shows the following error:

> ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Answer (score 42):

You can't use `include_vars` this way, it's only available for use under `tasks`.
If `sample_tasks.yml` is a list of tasks, you also can't use it on playbook level. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526100/2795592) for explanation.

You can use `vars_files` like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - sample_vault.yml
  tasks:
    name: "free task"
    command: ls -a
```

Or pass a file as extra variables:

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass -e @sample_vault.yml myplaybook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for great reply! I was facing problem with `include_vars` from vaulted file as `environment` in ansible 2+, by switching to `vars_files` evrything works!