# dynamic include var files at playbook level

Tags: ansible

Currently I have one big var file (vars/apps.yml) and all my playbooks look like this:

```
name: my playbook
vars_files:
  - vars/apps.yml
roles:
  - somerole
```

This works, but now I'd like to change my setup. As my `apps.yml` got really big and messy, I want to split it into multiple files (one file per app). So I need a possibility to load *all* vars files into my playbook. *It is ok to change all my playbook once, but I do not want to change all my playbooks every time I add a new var file.*

My 1. attempt was to have the multiple yml files plus an `apps.yml` which includes all other files - so I don't have to change anything in my playbooks.
Sadly, var files doesn't support include.

My 2. attempt was to replace

```
vars_files:
  - vars/apps.yml
```

with

```
include_vars:
  dir: vars
```

But that also failed because `include_vars` is only supported at tasks-level, not at playbook-level.

So now I'm out of ideas how to dynamically load multiple var files at playbook level.

---

Edit:

As there is some confusion, here is the full playbook I try to execute (using include_vars):

```
- name: debug
  hosts: localhost
  include_vars:
    dir: vars
  roles:
    - apache
```

This leads to `ERROR! 'include_vars' is not a valid attribute for a Play`
And as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811338/1654763), `include_vars` is only available under tasks.

Comment: You are confusing playbooks with plays. And what exactly is the problem with `include_vars`?

Comment: Ah sorry! As I understand, `include_vars` only works when I define it under `tasks` but not at top level of my playbook.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I edited my question.

Comment: You get an error. Because you need to use `include_vars` under `tasks`, which you seem to know already. What's the point in consciously introducing errors to code and asking about them on StackOverflow?

Comment: I don't have any `tasks` section (neither in my playbooks nor in my roles) so I'm looking for a way to load multiple vars files (without having to define a list of *all* var files in *all* playbooks)

Comment: Please get some understanding of the tools you are trying to use before asking about them on SO. If you have no `tasks`, then your playbooks do nothing. And in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933528/dynamic-include-var-files-at-playbook-level?noredirect=1#comment90836966_51933528) surprisingly you seemed to have `tasks`, now not... Also learn the vocabulary, I already told you you are confusing playbooks with plays.

Comment: Regarding that comment, I'm sorry, I often use `I` as a synonym for `(some)one` (not **I** defined under tasks but **one** has to define it there). Thanks for that hint, I'll learn vocabulary.

Comment: Well, currently my playbooks are working fine without `tasks` (except the include_vars issue)... so your advise is *rewrite all my playbooks to use tasks*?