# Ansible playbook condition fails when variable has a default value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Given the following playbook (`deployment.yml`):

```
---
- name: Debug
  hosts: applicationservers
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{add_host_entries | default('false')}}"
  - debug: msg="{{add_host_entries | default('false') == 'true'}}"
  - debug: msg="Add host entries = {{add_host_entries | default('false') == 'true'}}"

- include: add_host_entries.yml
  when: add_host_entries | default('false') == 'true'
```

The condition to include `add_host_entries.yml` always fails, even if all of the above debug messages print some sort of `true` (I know that in the first debug message it's a String, whereas the other two result in Booleans).

When I omit the part with the default value, `add_host_entries.yml` will be executed:

```
  when: add_host_entries
```

I need this default value behaviour though, because it's an optional value which is only set on certain stages.

## Other Attempts (without success)

### Brackets

```
  when: (add_host_entries | default('false')) == 'true'
```

### Casting to boolean

```
  when: add_host_entries|default('false')|bool
```

## Other Sources and Information

Here are all the resources needed to reproduce the problem.

### `add_host_entries.yml`

```
---
- name: add_host_entries
  hosts: applicationservers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Add Host Entries"
```

### `inventory`

```
[applicationservers]
127.0.0.1

[all:vars]
add_host_entries=true
```

### Call

```
markus@lubuntu:~/foobar$ ansible-playbook deployment.yml -i inventory
```

### Versions

```
markus@lubuntu:~/foobar$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides

markus@lubuntu:~/foobar$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.1.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to conditionally include **playbook**. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526100/2795592) answer about different include types.

The thing is, this only works when variable is defined **before** Ansible parses your playbook.
But you try to define `add_host_entries` as host-level fact (group variable) – these variables are not yet defined during parse time.

If you call your playbook with `-e add_host_entries=true` your condition will work as expected, because extra-vars are known during parse time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bool` to convert the string value of `add_host_entries` into a boolean and then the condition will work.

```
---
- name: Debug
  hosts: applicationservers
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="{{add_host_entries | default('false')}}"
  - debug: msg="{{add_host_entries | default('false') == 'true'}}"
  - debug: msg="Add host entries = {{add_host_entries | default('false') == 'true'}}"

- include: add_host_entries.yml
  when: add_host_entries | default('false') | bool
```

Comment: Actually, see Konstantins answer as well. He's right about using conditions at playbook level. The inventory is not taken into account at this stage.