# How can I set a variable in a playbook's `name` parameter?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following playbook and struggling to understand how to pass it the `application_name` variable:

```
---

- name: Initial configuration for a {{ application_name }} server
  hosts: all
  vars:
    - update_apt_cache: yes
  vars_files:
    - roles/base/defaults/main.yml

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="reading from group {{ groups }} and application name {{ application_name }}"
```

The issue is that the first `application_name` (in the `name` parameter) never works, though the second instance (defined in the task) works fine. How can I get the first instance to work as well? I've tried both defining the variable in the inventory...

```
[mygroup:vars]
application_name=my_application_name
```

...and in `group_vars` (`./group_vars/mygroup/vars.yml`)...

```
application_name: my_application_name
```

...but both of these do not fill the `name` parameter - only the `{{ application_name }}` found in the `tasks` section of the playbook.

Is there a way to fill in the first `application_name` variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible playbook condition fails when variable has a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863809/ansible-playbook-condition-fails-when-variable-has-a-default-value)

Comment: Playbook is a file, its name is stored in the filesystem, and it doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use the playbook name in the manner you want to.  group_vars aren't loaded until after the playbook name is displayed. To fill in the `application_name` in the playbook name you would either have to define it in the playbook vars section

```
- name: Initial configuration for a {{ application_name }} server
  hosts: all
  vars:
    - update_apt_cache: yes
    - application_name: foo
```

or with extra-vars on the command line

```
ansible-playbook -e "application_name=foo" your_playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, did you tried to quote variable?

```
- name: 'Initial configuration for a {{ application_name }} server'
```