# Can I run a playbook depending on the base machine

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have playbooks for Nagios installation for both Ubuntu and CentOS machines. How can I call the playbooks depending on the base machine?

I want to load `nagios_ubuntu` playbook when it is an Ubuntu machine and `nagios_centos` playbook for CentOS.

Comment: What does "load" mean for you in the context of ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 include: ubuntu.yml
 when: ansible_distribution == "Debian"

 include: centos.yml
 when: ansible_distribution == "Centos"
```

Be aware of this:  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes
and of this: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_module.html

Comment: In Ansible 2.4 you want `import_playbook:` instead of `include:` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't *include playbook **for** host*. Playbooks have `hosts` directive defined inside. See [playbook/tasks include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525235/how-should-an-include-playbook-be-different-from-a-standalone-one/38526100#38526100)

So you can have tasks include for different OSes, in this case you may want to use dynamic include statement in your playbook:

```
- include_tasks: "nagios_{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise an example described in [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#operating-system-and-distribution-variance) section with `group_by`.

You would still have to modify the playbooks themselves to contain an appropriate `hosts` declaration, for example:

`nagios_centos.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: nagios_centos
# ... the rest of the play
```

`nagios_ubuntu.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: nagios_ubuntu
# ... the rest of the play
```

Main playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
     - group_by:
         key: nagios_{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}

- import_playbook: nagios_centos.yml

- import_playbook: nagios_ubuntu.yml
```

Because of `hosts` definition, only one of the playbooks would effectively run.