# playbook within playbook with return code

Tags: ansible

I want to include a `playbook` in the master playbook. However if anything fails in the include playbooks, master playbook should exit out without running further tasks specified in it.

**MasterPlaybook.yml**

```
    - include: playbook1.yml
    - include: playbook2.yml

    - name: copy file
      shell: echo "hello"

    - name: list other one
      shell: echo "Hi"
```

playbook1.yml

```
  - name: list task
    shell: ls /tmp/ | grep text.html


   - name: list file 
     shell: ls /root/ | grep text2.html
```

playbook2.yml

```
   - name: list task
     shell: ls /tmp/ | grep text.html


   - name: list file 
     shell: ls /root/ | grep text2.html
```

So in the above example if any task fail in `playbook1.yml`, the rest of the tasks in master should not get executed

Answer (score 2):

For playbooks you can use `any_errors_fatal: yes`.

For tasks you can use `rescue` block `meta: end_play`.

Update:

You have [list of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526100/2795592), and not a playbook. So your filenames are misleading.

Anyway, you may want something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - include_tasks: file1.yml
      rescue:
        - meta: end_play
    - include_tasks: file2.yml
    - shell: echo ok
```

In this case if any task in file1.yml fails, `meta: end_play` will fire to stop playbook right away.

Comment: For tasks, I can manage ignore_errors Im more concerned about not executing playbooks. Can you please share an example how it can be achived with rescue block meta: end_play

Comment: Please provide MCVE playbooks in your original post, so I can edit them to fullfill your requirements.

Comment: Done, please check